# ordering = ['-created'] what it means in Django? why we use - sign in ordering?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Below is my code.

```
class Basecalss(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

   class Meta:
      abstract = True
      ordering = ['-created']
```

Here why we use - sing before created, what it means??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A leading negative sign indicates *descending* order.

So `"created"` would be oldest first (ascending), and `"-created"` would indicate newest first.

This is documented under [querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/).